# css nav bar does not extend t

Tags: css, format, navbar

My css nav bar does not extend to the end of the page. I have a box around each menu link but I would like that color to extend for another 700px so that it's not just white space.

This is my html

```
 <ul id="button">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resum&eacute;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
 </ul>
```

This is my css

```
#button {
    padding: 0px;
}
#button li {
    display: inline;

}
#button li a {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #4169E1;
    color: #fff;

    }
#button li a:hover {
    background-color: #E30800;
    margin-top:-2px;
    padding-bottom:12px;
}
```

Comment: screenshot can be found here
http://www.23hq.com/stothek/photo/12349117/original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this

```
#button {padding: 0px;float:left;width:100%}
```

Comment: That works except I needed to also add the background-color but thanks, that resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Add an height attribute to your css.  A min-height may also help.  Using a % instead of pixels will make it fluid and nicer.